# SQL agrupando os dados iguais, mas mostrando as fotos dos registros

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um SLQ que retorna a quantidade de registros repetidos agrupados,
Porem minha necessidade e que list todas as fotos dos registros duplicados

```
SELECT count(Longitude) AS registros, id_local, Longitude,Latitude,nome_local,endereco,pic FROM `locais` GROUP BY Longitude,Latitude ORDER BY `nome_local` ASC
```

A consulta me retorna que tenho 2 registros em uma mesma latitude, eu preciso que me de o nome das 3 fotos que se encontram em cada registro, porem agrupado apenas com o nome do local

Answer (score 2):

Para esta situação, eu utilizaria o GROUP_CONCAT() do MySQL, desta maneira, para cada nome diferente encontrado durante o agrupamento, eu teria o valor separado por vírgula. Ficaria algo como abaixo (imaginando que as fotos estejam no campo **pic**):

```
SELECT count(Longitude) AS registros, id_local, Longitude,Latitude,nome_local,endereco, GROUP_CONCAT(pic) as pics FROM `locais` GROUP BY Longitude,Latitude ORDER BY `nome_local` ASC
```

Desta maneira, no código faria as tratativas necessárias. O resultado para essa coluna seria algo como "foto1, foto2, foto3...".